Responsive Design for Phone and Tablet
I have an app that I want to support both Phone and the Tablet, but not the same layout as the Phone stretched over Tablet.
Re-arrangement of the layout is expected, just like responsive web, where subcomponents on the page re-layout as viewport changes or browser is resized.
For instance, on the Phone, stack Views on top of each other (current solution) but on the Tablet, ClientOverview and TaskManagement View will be displayed side-by-side.

const BusinessApp = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Dashboard View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Dashboard View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Key metrics and performance indicators.</Text>
      </View>

      {/* Client Overview View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Client Overview View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Client accounts, interactions, and status overview.</Text>
      </View>

      {/* Task Management View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Task Management View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Manage and assign team tasks efficiently.</Text>
      </View>

      {/* Financial Summary View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Financial Summary View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Overview of revenue, expenses, and profitability.</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#f8f9fa',
  },
  section: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  content: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});

export default BusinessApp;



You can implement a flexible design for your application by dynamically adjusting the flex-direction based on the device type. Set the layout to 'row' for tablets and 'column' for smartphones to optimize the user interface.
To determine if the device is a tablet or a smartphone, you can use:
import Device from 'react-native-device-info';
const isTablet = Device.isTablet();

However, a more versatile approach is to use the Dimensions component in React Native. This allows you to adjust the layout dynamically by checking the window width and deciding if it's wide enough to display a row layout or if a column layout is more appropriate:
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const isRow = windowWidth > [your_breakpoint];

This is an example of how you can achieve this:
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Device from 'react-native-device-info';

const BusinessApp = () => {
  // Determine the screen width and whether it's a tablet or smartphone
  const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const isTablet = Device.isTablet();
  
  // Use row layout for tablets and wider screens, column for smartphones
  const isRow = isTablet || windowWidth > 768; // Adjust 768 as the breakpoint for layout change

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { flexDirection: isRow ? 'row' : 'column' }]}>
      {/* Dashboard View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Dashboard View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Key metrics and performance indicators.</Text>
      </View>

      {/* Client Overview View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Client Overview View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Client accounts, interactions, and status overview.</Text>
      </View>

      {/* Task Management View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Task Management View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Manage and assign team tasks efficiently.</Text>
      </View>

      {/* Financial Summary View */}
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Financial Summary View</Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Overview of revenue, expenses, and profitability.</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#f8f9fa',
  },
  section: {
    flex: 1, 
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  content: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});

export default BusinessApp;

